# Induction with other base case in Coq

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic

I am trying to proof the pigeonhole problem in Coq. Therefore I have the following lemma that I want to proof:

```
Lemma pigeon_hole :
forall m n, m < n ->
forall f, (forall i, i < n -> f i < m) ->
exists i, i < n /\
exists j, j < n /\ i <> j /\ f i = f j.
```

From my teacher I have got the hint that a useful tactic to automatically prove equalities and inequalities between natural numbers is

```
omega.
```

But I doubt if that is relevant here.

I thought that it could be done with induction as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910741/constructive-proof-of-pigeonhole-principle.

If I try to do induction on n, I get the base case with n=0. Here I first do 'intros.' and then 'induction n.'.

But I want the base case n=2. Is there a possibility in Coq do get that or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question you linked to contains this off-hand comment:

> The case n=1 is impossible

This is good enough for a human mathematician, but not for Coq. You can tell Coq that you only want to prove cases where n >= 2 by adding that to the premises of the lemma:

```
Lemma pigeon_hole :
  forall m n,
  n >= 2 ->    (* added this *)
  m < n ->
  forall f,
  (forall i, i < n -> f i < m) ->
  exists i, i < n /\
  exists j, j < n /\ i <> j /\ f i = f j.
```

Now this statement should be provable. To get to a state where your induction starts at n = 2, you could argue like this on paper:

By cases on n.

- n = 0: impossible by the precondition n >= 2.
- n = 1: impossible by the precondition n >= 2.
- n >= 2: by induction...

You can do the same in Coq by using destruct on `n` twice:

```
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct n.
```

We made a case distinction between n = 0 and n >= 0 (i.e., `n = S n'` for some `n'`). We are in a proof state with:

```
H : 0 >= 2
```

This false hypothesis is exactly the kind of thing that `omega` can discharge for you:

```
  - omega.
```

In the other case we know that n >= 1. This is closer to n >= 2 but still not enough, so we can again do a case distinction on n to get rid of the n = 1 case:

```
  - destruct n.
    + omega.
    +
```

The proof state is now:

```
1 subgoal
m, n : nat
H : S (S n) >= 2
H0 : m < S (S n)
f : nat -> nat
H1 : forall i : nat, i < S (S n) -> f i < m
______________________________________(1/1)
exists i : nat,
  i < S (S n) /\ (exists j : nat, j < S (S n) /\ i <> j /\ f i = f j)
```

So all original uses of `n` have been replaced by `S (S n)`, i.e., a value that is >= 2.

You should be able to continue from here using `induction n`.

Answer (score 0):

The base is `n = 0`, but you can get rid of this.  Then you have an inductive case where you are looking at the formula with `S n` every where.  If you do `destruct n as [ | n]`, then have two cases, the first on is for `1`, and can probably get rid of that one again, then if do `destruct n as [ | n]` again, you will have to take care of the case `2`.  So this will play the role of your base case.  Now, the remaining case will be about the same formula but where the initial `n` is replace by `S (S (S n))` and the induction hypothesis is about the formula is already true for `S (S n)`.  That will give you an induction proof starting with base case `n = 2`.

But still the statement is true for `n = 0` and `n = 1` and you need to prove these cases on the side.

### Second possibility (which would work for a base case at a higher constant)

Alternatively, you can get of the base case by showing that n is 0 is not possible, then when looking at the inductive case, you can start the proof by

```
destruct (le_lt_dec 2 n).
```

This will give you two cases: one where `2 <= n` and you have to prove the property for `S n`, and one where `n < 2`.  For the latter, you should be able that this is not possible (I did not check whether you should 2 or 1 as the testing bound).